# PostgreSQL Database Structure for Storing User Progress

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to set up a database structure for storing user progress in an app. Right now I'm using PostgreSQL to store user information and other data related to the app. I'm not sure how to how to structure the database for when the user makes progress, i.e. unlocks a certain level. I was thinking of making a relational database that has all of the users as a row and then as columns has all of the things they can possible unlock and then store true or false values in it, but this seems rather inefficient. Is there a better way to store this information?

Comment: your implementation would make list of possible achievements more or less static. I'd rather go with users+achievements pair in two columns

Answer (score 0):

I would rather add achievements as rows, not columns, eg:

```
t=# create table achievements (i smallserial primary key, ach text);
CREATE TABLE
t=# create table user_achievements (i serial, user_id int, ach_id smallint references achievements(i), level int, achieved timestamptz default now());
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into achievements (ach) values('blah');
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into user_achievements(user_id,ach_id,level) values(1,1,1);
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into user_achievements(user_id,ach_id,level) values(1,1,2);
INSERT 0 1
t=# select * from user_achievements;
 i | user_id | ach_id | level |           achieved
---+---------+--------+-------+-------------------------------
 1 |       1 |      1 |     1 | 2018-01-29 08:25:32.018466+00
 2 |       1 |      1 |     2 | 2018-01-29 08:25:34.089929+00
```

Comment: Wouldn't I have to call the whole table, or comb through the whole table, every time I wanted to know the user's achievement progress though?